# renaming php file with value from input text field?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, text, input

I'm trying to rename a file as I'm uploading it using the JQuery uploader. I'm pretty far already, here's the important part of my UploadHandler.php:

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, 
    $error, $index = null, $content_range = null)
{

    $file = new stdClass();
    $file = new stdClass();

    $name = "Name"; 

    $file->name =  /* basename(stripslashes($name)) . */
        $this->get_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range);
    $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($size));
    $file->type = $type;
    if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
        $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
        $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
        if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
            mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
        }
        $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
        $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
        $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
            if ($append_file) {
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
            }
        } else {
            // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
            file_put_contents(
                $file_path,
                fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
            );
        }
```

As you see, with the variable `$name` I have set it to "Name" which works great if I want all of my uplaoded files to be called name. But I want it so people can enter in their name and it renames the file to that, which I basically need to just pass into my `$name` variable. But the question is: How do I do that? I've tried using ajax:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

var dataString = $("#nama").val();

 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "server/php/index.php",
data: { 'dataString': dataString },
cache: false,
success: function()
    {
        alert("Order Submitted");
    }
});
```

but that simply didn't do anything. Also here's the html index file, in case taht helps:

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <!--
            /*
             * jQuery File Upload Plugin Demo 7.4
             * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
             *
             * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
             * https://blueimp.net
             *
             * Licensed under the MIT license:
             * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
             */
            -->
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
            <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Senior Slide Show</title>
            <meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bar and preview images for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (Google App Engine, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- Generic page styles -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
            <!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
            <!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
            <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
            <!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
            <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
            <!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="brand" href="http://www.dpnews.org">Dos Pueblos Senior Slide Show</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse">
                            <!--<ul class="nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/">Demo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#download">Download</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">Source Code</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">Documentation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#support">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://blueimp.net">&copy; Sebastian Tschan</a></li>
                            </ul>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Dos Pueblos Senior Slide Show 2013Uploader</h1>
                </div>
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Hello everyone! Welcome to the Senior Slide Show uploader.<br>
                    To use this uploader, all you have to do is click the "Add Files" button, and pick out your video/image. Maximum file size is 2GB.<br>
                    After that, just click the "Start" button next to the queued file. It will go right to the Senior Slide Show.</p>
                </blockquote>
                <br>
                <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
                <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
                    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000000" />
                    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
                    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                        <div class="span7">
                            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                                <span>Add files...</span>
                                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                            </span>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                                <span>Start upload</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                                <span>Cancel upload</span>
                            </button>
                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                                <span>Delete</span>
                            </button>-->
                            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                        </div>
                        <!-- The global progress information -->
                        <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                            <!-- The global progress bar -->
                            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
                    <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
                    <br>
                    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
                    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
                </form>
                <br>
                <!--<div class="well">
                    <h3>Demo Notes</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>The maximum file size for uploads in this demo is <strong>5 MB</strong> (default file size is unlimited).</li>
                        <li>Only image files (<strong>JPG, GIF, PNG</strong>) are allowed in this demo (by default there is no file type restriction).</li>
                        <li>Uploaded files will be deleted automatically after <strong>5 minutes</strong> (demo setting).</li>
                        <li>You can <strong>drag &amp; drop</strong> files from your desktop on this webpage with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Apple Safari.</li>
                        <li>Please refer to the <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">project website</a> and <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">documentation</a> for more information.</li>
                        <li>Built with Twitter's <a href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/">Bootstrap</a> toolkit and Icons from <a href="http://glyphicons.com/">Glyphicons</a>.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>-->
            </div>
            <!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
            <div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade" data-filter=":odd" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
                        <i class="icon-download"></i>
                        <span>Download</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
                        <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Slideshow</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
                        <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
                        <span>Next</span>
                        <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
            <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
            {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
                <tr class="template-upload fade">
                    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
                    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
                    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                    {% if (file.error) { %}
                        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
                    {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
                        <td>
                            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                            <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                                <span>Start</span>
                            </button>
                        {% } %}</td>
                    {% } else { %}
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    {% } %}
                    <td>{% if (!i) { %}
                        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                            <span>Cancel</span>
                        </button>
                    {% } %}</td>
                </tr>
            {% } %}
            </script>
            <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
            <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
            {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
                <tr class="template-download fade">
                    {% if (file.error) { %}
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
                        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
                    {% } else { %}
                        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
                        {% } %}</td>
                        <td class="name">
                            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    {% } %}
                    <td>
                        <!--<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                            <span>Delete</span>
                        </button>-->
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% } %}
            </script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
            <script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
            <!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
            <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
            <!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
            <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
            <!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
            <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
            <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
            <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
            <!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
            <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
            <!-- The File Upload file processing plugin -->
            <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
            <!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
            <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
            <!-- The main application script -->
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
            <!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: could you provide us link of file upload library ?

Comment: I added my full html index code

Answer (score 0):

..ok, I am not sure if I read your code well but since the $name was declared on the server side, how about declaring an empty variable and then passing the client selected (defined) value into it through Ajax. Then just declare the name as variable variable ($$name) with the new variable value. Would that work ? (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

..well,if you could pass the value through the GET variable you could do something like this:

Initiate the Ajax call:

```
function passname()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }

   else { xmllhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } 

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        var newname = document.getElementById("chosen_name").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET","receive_newname.php?value="+newname, true);
        xmlhttp.send()
      }
   }

}
```

.. an obviously you need to have the receiving PHP file receive_newname.php on the server (or in your case it could be in the same PHP server file you have) where you receive the $_GET['value'] and assign it to $name variable.

I think this could work :)  did not test it though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not very good at ajax, how would I go about doing that without refreshing the page?

Comment: ...I guess you could add onClick event to anything (sorry I did not read your HTML code yet) and do somethign like this: onclick="passname()"

Answer (score 0):

In your `server/php/index.php` file you're calling from AJAX, just call `$_POST['dataString']` to get what your user inputted ;)

In other words, you should affect your `$name` variable;

`$name = $_POST['dataString'];`

Comment: Thank you all, I resolved it at last! It turns out I didn't have to use ajax.. just called the GET method in my PHHP script to write to an external .txt file and opened taht txt file for my $name variable. Thanks for the help all!